# Configure a subdomain (Virtualhost) for phpMyAdmin

Tags: centos, php, virtual-host, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with configuring a subdomain (Virtualhost) for phpMyAdmin.

My current .conf look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName php.erichermansson.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@erichermansson.com

DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
        php_flag track_vars On
        php_flag register_globals Off
        php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
        php_value include_path .
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
        AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>

    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

<Directory setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you guys have a clue what the problem could be? It only access the Apache testpage.

Comment: In order to check if this is the problem, try to disable Apache testpage. it depends on what distro you are, but basically you shoul rename your `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` modifying the extension .conf in something else that apache will not read.

Answer (score 1):

All four of your <Directory> stanzas are defined with relative paths.  Directory paths must always be full absolute paths (or absolute paths with wildcards).

They are **NOT** interpreted as if they are relative to the DocumentRoot.

Try:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
...
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
...
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
...
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
...
</Directory>
```

From the Apache 2.2 documentation: (2.4 is the same)

> *<Directory>* and *</Directory>* are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories. Any directive that is allowed in a directory context may be used.
>
> Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string using Unix shell-style matching. In a wild-card string, ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters. You may also use [] character ranges.
>
> None of the wildcards match a `/' character, so *<Directory  */public_html>* will not match */home/user/public_html, but <Directory /home/*/public_html>* will match.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I tried changing it, but i still have the same problem - it access my Apache testpage.

Comment: Ok, this is only part of the answer because your vhost wouldn't work without fixing the Directory paths.  If this vhost isn't being served, that probably means that there is an earlier configuration that disables it.  Does centos use one large /etc/apache/httpd.conf file or does it split apache config like debian does, with vhosts in` /etc/apache2/sites-available` and `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?  if the latter, a) check the order of site definitions, and b) check that there's a symlink from sites-enabled to the actual vhost conf in sites-available.

Comment: I've set it up so it uses sites-available and sites-enabled and i also created a symlink between the sites-available and sites-enabled. It works for my other subdomains but I can't get this one to work. Any ideas?